# "Algebraic dimension" for finite-dimensional (non-associative) algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, noncommutative-algebra, dimension-theory-algebra, nonassociative-algebras

Let $V$ be some finite-dimensional vector space (over some field $\mathbb{K}$), then a [(possibly non-associative) algebra $A$ on $V$ corresponds to a bilinear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-associative_algebra) $V \times V \to V$. I prefer answers that can address this level of generality.

Given some (finite) subset $\{v_1, \dots, v_D\}$ of $A$, let $\mathscr{A}(v_1, \dots, v_D)$ denote the sub-algebra of $A$ **generated** by $\{v_1, \dots, v_D\}$, i.e. by applying the bilinear algebra product $V \times V \to V$ and linear combinations. ("Non-commutative and non-associative polynomials".)

> **Question:** Is there a notion of "algebraic dimension" for such algebras which reflects the minimal number $D$ of elements of $A$ needed to generate $A$, i.e. the smallest possible $D$ such that there exists a $\{v_1, \dots, v_D\} \subset A$ with $\mathscr{A}(v_1, \dots, v_D) = A$?
>
> What is the name of this notion of "algebraic dimension"? Any recommendations for references to read more about it?

**Comments:**

- A necessary, but obviously in general not sufficient, condition for such a generating set is that it be linearly independent. Therefore, if $N$ is the vector space dimension of $A$ (i.e. of $V$), then clearly in general $D \le N$, where $D$ denotes this "algebraic dimension".
- Also I think such a minimal $D$ has to exist e.g. by applying Zorn's lemma? But if such a concept doesn't exist in the literature because in general it doesn't exist or isn't well-defined, it would be helpful to explain why and/or provide a reference or counterexample.
- If this is well-defined, I still wouldn't expect such minimal "algebraically spanning" sets to necessarily satisfy the [matroid axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid), i.e. be as well behaved as the concept of linear independence. But you know that's a whole other can of worms.

**What I already tried (i.e. similar concepts that aren't what I'm looking for):**

- In cases when the algebra is sufficiently "free", then the [Krull dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension#For_non-commutative_rings) appears to coincide with this notion (cf. e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3504001/transcendence-degree-and-krull-dimension-of-finitely-generated-algebras)), or be off only by one, e.g. the polynomial algebra generated by two elements $\mathbb{K}[x,y]$ is $2$ (but maybe in my definition the value should be $3$ to include constant terms but anyway).

  Anyway the problem with Krull dimension for finite-dimensional algebras is that they all satisfy the descending chain condition, so they must have [deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension#For_non-commutative_rings) zero, so they must be (left+right) [Artinian rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3743185/606791), so necessarily have [Krull dimension zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27145/why-are-artinian-rings-of-krull-dimension-0). So basically Krull dimension penalizes "non-freeness" too much to be useful for studying finite-dimensional algebras in this way.
- "[Algebras of finite type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_algebra)" and/or "algebraic independence" (cf. e.g. [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362911/what-does-it-mean-for-elements-to-be-algebraically-independent)[[2]](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence)[[3]](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlgebraicallyIndependent.html)[[4]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence)). Both of these concepts necessarily assume commutative and associative algebras (basically so we can reduce things to quotients of polynomial algebras?). Also there doesn't appear to be a term for the minimal number of elements in an algebraically independent set. But anyway what I want I guess could be considered the generalization of this to the non-commutative, non-associative setting, so I guess anything that can be written as a quotient of a [free non-associative algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-associative_algebra#Free_non-associative_algebra).
- [Dilworth number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893951/rings-with-given-dimension-in-a-specific-sense-related-to-generators-of-idea#comment4151777_1893951) (cf. this *very* [closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893951/rings-with-given-dimension-in-a-specific-sense-related-to-generators-of-idea)). The finite-dimensionality presumably makes all finite-dimensional algebras not only (left+right) Artinian rings (satisfying DCC) but also (left+right) Noetherian rings. (Apparently Artinian implies Noetherian [even in the non-commutative case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069809/on-a-proof-that-left-artinian-implies-left-noetherian), so maybe this observation is redundant.) Again, this is *ridiculously* close to what I want, but again it assumes that things are commutative and associative and thus quotients of polynomial rings, which again is not an assumption that I want to make. Also the question is technically asking about ideals and not subrings (i.e. sub-algebras) - that may not be relevant here because $A$ is both a (non-proper) ideal and subring, but for what it's worth.